# Veridis Biometrics demo is not working

Tags: biometrics

I have purchased a Futronic FS88H fingerprint. I have donwloaded the sdk  version 5.0. Tried to get the demo working, but not success. I have noticed that the fingerprint's lights aren't activated. It is like the program is not activating the fingerprinter. Also I have tried the .net and java examples. I got the same result. 
when I run the FingerprintCaptureBasicApp that came in the drivers folder, it reads my finger, the lights are activated, so I confirmed that tha fingerprint is properly connected to my computer.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Futronic has changed the CMOS sensor, so in order to get the Veridis SDK working with the new futronic  devices, you have to update the .dll (ftrScanAPI.dll) for the futronic scan api, which is located in the bin folder inside installation folder of the Veridis SDK.

You can download the Worked example from Futronic's website here: http://www.futronic-tech.com/download/WorkedEx.zip then copy the .dll from the extracted folder.

Answer (score 0):

Veridis 5.0 also never worked with Digitalpersona 4000B fingerprint reader last time I tried. You could try using Griaule SDK or Verifinger SDK.